# MATLAB: SQL-style join operation

Tags: sql, matlab, join

I would like to do an SQL-style join with Matlab. I could do it by creating datasets (stats toolbox), doing the join, converting back and deleting the datasets again:

```
A1 = [10 10 20 20 30 30 50 50]';
B1 = (10:10:70)';
B2 = (1:7)';

dsA = dataset({A1, 'Key'});
dsB = dataset({B1, 'Key'}, {B2, 'Idx'});
dsA = join(dsA, dsB, 'key', 'Key');
```

Result:

```
Key    Idx
10     1  
10     1  
20     2  
20     2  
30     3  
30     3  
50     5  
50     5
```

My Question: Is there another way of doing this, *without using datasets and without for loops*?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: I know matlab and I know SQL but I cannot understand your question (at least easily!). Forget about datasets, just in plain matlab what do you want? you want to go from A1 and B1 to B2?! A join in sql is a way to look up and merge elements of one table (vector here) from/with a second one using a shared key.

Comment: What I want to is: 
SELECT A1, B2 from A,B WHERE A1=B1;
Which is what the proposed solution from Amro does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, you could simply use [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html):

```
[~,loc] = ismember(A1,B1);
dsA = [B1(loc) B2(loc)]
```

result:

```
dsA =
    10     1
    10     1
    20     2
    20     2
    30     3
    30     3
    50     5
    50     5
```

Note: this assumes that all the elements in `A1` are found in `B1`. If that not always the case, you could use the first output of ISMEMBER to filter the zero-values in `loc`...

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the loc argument.