# MATLAB Combine matrices of different dimensions, filling values of corresponding indices

Tags: matlab, join, matrix, fill

I have two matrices, `22007x3` and `352x2`. The first column in each is an index, most (but not all) of which are shared (i.e. x1 contains indices that aren't in x2).

I would like to combine the two matrices into a `22007x4` matrix, such that column 4 is filled in with the values that correspond to particular indices in both original matrices.

For example:

```
x1 =
    1   1   5
    1   2   4
    1   3   5
    2   1   1
    2   2   1
    2   3   2

x2 =
    1   15.5
    2   -5.6
```

becomes

```
x3 =
    1   1   5   15.5
    1   2   4   15.5
    1   3   5   15.5
    2   1   1   -5.6
    2   2   1   -5.6
    2   3   2   -5.6
```

I've tried something along the lines of

```
x3(1:numel(x1),1:3)=x1;
x3(1:numel(x2(:,2)),4)=x2(:,2);
```

but firstly I get the error

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

and then I can't figure out I would fill the rest of it.

An important point is that there are not necessarily an equal number of rows per index in my data.

How might I make this work?

Comment: does x2(:,1) contain repeats?

Comment: @Dan no, it does not.

Comment: will x1(:,1) and x2(:,1) always have all the numbers from 1 to their respective maximums?

Comment: @Dan Also no. This is one of the reasons why my data are so incredibly awkward to deal with.

Comment: I guess the real question is what do you want to do when there is a number in the first column of x1 that is not in x2?

Comment: @carlosdc Just to clarify, all values in x2(:,1) are in x1(:,1), but not vice versa. Any data in x1 that doesn't have corresponding data in x2 can just be ignored.

Comment: @8eastFromThe3ast: ignored how? dropped and eliminated ignored? filled in with a default value ignored?

Comment: @carlosdc dropped and eliminated ignored. For this, I'm only interested in indices that have data in both matrices.

Comment: @8eastFromThe3ast: You might also find this useful: [Is there a function in MATLAB that can merge two matrices based on column or row labels?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-143J0O/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-143J0O)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking Amro's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547550/matlab-sql-style-join-operation)

```
[~, loc] = ismember(x1(:,1), x2(:,1));
```

ismember's second argument returns the location in x2 where each element of x1 can be found (or 0 if it can't)

```
a = x2(loc(loc > 0), 2);
```

get the relevant values using these row indices but excluding the zeros, hence the `loc > 0` mask. You have to exclude these as 1, they are not in x2 and 2 you can't index with `0`.

Make a new column of default values to stick on the end of x1. I think `NaN()` is probably better but `zeros()` is also fine maybe

```
newCol = NaN(size(x1,1),1)
```

Now use logical indexing to get the locations of the non zero elements and put `a` in those locations

```
newCol(loc > 0) = a
```

Finnaly stick it on the end

```
x3 = [x1, newCol]
```

Comment: Actually this will error if x1(:,1) has numbers not in x2(:,1) :/

Comment: success! Brilliant! Thanks very much. @Dan any chance you could talk me through the steps?

Comment: @8eastFromThe3ast oops i made a rookie error in there using find instead of logical indexing, you should drop the `find`. see latest edit