# Use matlab to arrange excel data

Tags: matlab, import-from-excel

I have data in excel like this:

```
id  date    value
a   9/17/2012   0.25
a   9/18/2012   0.48
a   9/19/2012   0.29
a   9/20/2012   0.46
a   9/21/2012   0.17
a   9/24/2012   0.89
a   9/25/2012   0.20
a   9/26/2012   0.65
a   9/27/2012   0.26
b   9/17/2012   0.83
b   9/18/2012   0.87
b   9/19/2012   0.40
b   9/20/2012   0.33
b   9/21/2012   0.71
b   9/24/2012   0.13
b   9/25/2012   0.91
b   9/26/2012   0.73
b   9/27/2012   0.87
c   9/17/2012   0.47
c   9/18/2012   0.15
c   9/19/2012   0.73
c   9/20/2012   0.47
c   9/21/2012   0.03
c   9/24/2012   0.23
c   9/25/2012   0.21
c   9/26/2012   0.39
c   9/27/2012   0.77
```

and I would like to use Matlab to re-arrange to:

```
date        a       b       c
9/17/2012   0.25    0.83    0.47
9/18/2012   0.48    0.87    0.15
9/19/2012   0.29    0.40    0.73
9/20/2012   0.46    0.33    0.47
9/21/2012   0.17    0.71    0.03
9/24/2012   0.89    0.13    0.23
9/25/2012   0.20    0.91    0.21
9/26/2012   0.65    0.73    0.39
9/27/2012   0.26    0.87    0.77
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

1. `importdata` or `xlsread`
2. `join` (statistics toolbox) or see [MATLAB Combine matrices of different dimensions, filling values of corresponding indices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16217059/395857).