# Combine Matlab Arrays based on first column

Tags: matlab

I have 2 arrays:

array A (4x2):

```
1 2
4 13
5 14
6 13
```

array B (3x2):

```
2 11
4 34  
7 56
```

I want to get (6x3):

```
1  2
2      11
4  13  34
5  14
6  13
7      56
```

i.e. combine above 2 arrays of unequal size based on elements in first column and create a new array with columns of 2 arrays as distinct columns.

Thanks

Comment: And what are you gonna use to fill the empty elements?

Comment: You can use `join` (statistics toolbox) or see http://stackoverflow.com/q/16217059/395857.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
c = unique([a(:,1); b(:,1)]);
c(:,2:3) = NaN;
c(ismember(c(:,1), a(:,1)), 2) = a(:,2);
c(ismember(c(:,1), b(:,1)), 3) = b(:,2)
```

Comment: If `a` or `b` can contain `0`, simply add `c(:,2:3) = NaN;` after the first line and remove the last line

Comment: @Luis Mendo .. thanks for the note. It was a good insight which I overlooked.

Comment: Are we assuming that the first columns of `A` and `B` are always sorted?

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia if not you can use the `'stable'` flag in `unique`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, that's a better way