# Compare two matrices according to first row in each matrix (matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'll briefly explain my purpose in case another solution would be much easier.

I have a server and a system. The system sends a "live-stat" packet twice a second and logs the time it was sent (epoch time). The server receives the packet and logs the receiving time.
I would like to know which of the packets arrived and the latency of their arrival.

Currently I'm inserting this data to an unorganized matrix and i would like to compare the two matrices (server and system) to calculate the latency.

Is there any matlab command that could help me?

Another point is that I don't know how to get a numerical value for the latency, is there any formula or tool that i could use? (I''m currently going to show the deviation of the latency on a graph).
I'm talking about 500,000 packets per system and i'm testing this on ~50 systems so i'm looking for the most efficient calculation.

Comment: [diff](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) but it seems too obvious to me? Surely you must have thought of that...?

Comment: Depends on how you organize the data within your matrices, please give an example of the matrix-structure.

Comment: I guess you are looking for the equivalent of a SQL-join: Similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981570/join-matrices-in-matlab) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547550/matlab-sql-style-join-operation).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. knedlsepp suggestions are working for me. I am not very familiar with the DB world so I asked to know which function exists. The innerjoin function does the job for me.